# return data using variable variables

Tags: php, arrays

```
$raw_data = array ('data' => array ('id' => 'foo'));
$fields = array ('id_source' => "data['id']"); 

foreach ($raw_data as $data) {
    foreach ($fields as $key => $path) {
        var_dump ($data['id']);
        var_dump ($$path);
    }
}
```

The first var_dump gives me the correct value of `foo`. However, the second one gives me `Undefined variable: data['id']`. Can anyone tell me why that would be the case, especially since the first var_dump worked confirming the variable `$data['id']` is set.

I realized this example is basic and I could just do `$data[$key]` and change `$fields = array ('id_source' => 'id');` but I want to be able to go deeper into the multidimensional arrays when needed. That is why I'm trying to do my original approach.

Comment: did you tried what i given ?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - I did thanks. But that returns the full array and not the selected value from the key.

Comment: You can't use index in such maner in variable of variables.Just $a = 'data'; ${$a}['id'];

Comment: You can not do like that what you want, because it is array variable, not normal string variable. thanks.

Comment: That's compound data, and the *name* of the variable is `data`, which has a stored value for the key `'id'`.